# is it possible to pull out a flex-item in the middle and stretch it to 100% width as a secondary row in html on resize?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to pull out a flex-item in the middle and stretch it to 100% width as a second row in HTML on resize?

I have the follow flex-items wrapped in a flex-box

**Item-A   Item-B   Item-C   Item-D   Item-E**

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
  <div>Item-A</div>
  <div>Item-B</div>
  <div>Item-C</div>
  <div>Item-D</div>
  <div>Item-E</Div>
</div>
```

On smaller devices, I want the Item-B to be pulled out of the row and display as a second row but inside the parent container. Is it possible to do with CSS flex?

Note: I am using bootstrap as CSS framework

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `flex-basis: 100%` to make your item full width, and `order: 1` to place it after all the other items in the container. In the snippet below I've set this to happen on devices smaller than 500px:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  outline: 1px dashed tomato;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .item-b {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item item-a">a</div>
  <div class="item item-b">b</div>
  <div class="item item-c">c</div>
  <div class="item item-d">d</div>
  <div class="item item-e">e</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `order` and media queries to achieve the results.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > div {
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 25%;
}

.item3 {
  order: 5;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.item4 {
  order: 3;
}

.item5 {
  order: 4;
}
  
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  }
  
  .item3 {
    order: 3;
    flex-grow: 0;
  }
  
  .item4 {
    order: 4;
  }
  
  .item5 {
    order: 5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">Item1</div>
  <div class="item2">Item2</div>
  <div class="item3">Item3</div>
  <div class="item4">Item4</div>
  <div class="item5">Item5</div>
</div>
```